# Some concern about putting a payment/transactional app on GAE

Tags: performance, google-app-engine, bigtable

I'm trying to build a shopping-cart-like webapp on GAE. So far, I haven't deployed anything on GAE still and just keep doing some POC locally... then, I read this:

http://borglin.net/gwt-project/?page_id=688

It surprised me when I read through those "weaknesses" and I'm pretty worried about whether it's a good choice putting the app on GAE. Would someone, esp who has experience building a real-world app with cash transactions, please give me some ideas/share your thoughts?

1. The article said GAE has "No https support for your domain". Is it true? I thought what I need to do is just point my domain `https://www.abc.com` to GAE `https://abc.appspot.com` ...
2. For BigTable, I understand it would be quite hard to build analytic/statistical functionalities in my app (e.g. provide a monthly transaction summary). Does anyone has any experience to handle such situation...? export data from BigTable to RDBMS and do some SQL ...?
3. The articale also said that BigTable has a bad write performance: "I'm lucky to get 100 writes per second in a GAE request. " Is it true? I cannot find any figure to support/disprove it ..
4. I'm now using SpringMVC + Objectify at server-side. Is it too heavy for GAE ? Some said Spring could make a long cold start ... how cold is it? How long would it take to init an app with like, 20+ different pages/controllers, and 20+ kinds of entities/DAO ..?? Any ballpark figure ..??

p.s. If you know any real world app built on GAE, please kindly share here? Because I wanna know how far (or how big) my app could be.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

1) That is true. https is only supported for .appspot.com. A very big shortcoming.

2) That's not really true, you can do any kind of monthly summary reports using the remoting api if you need to do complex joins and such. You can also export the data and use an offline tool

3) I haven't seen that kind of write performance bottleneck, but there is eventual consistency to deal with. That said, 100 writes/second is not a small number...

4) I would avoid spring on appengine. A lot of people use it happily but I found that startup time was very slow and that caused problems.

Answer (score 1):

1. The SSL for Custom Domains is in [testing phase](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2011/10/app-engine-ssl-for-custom-domains-in.html). Please note that HTTPS/SSL was not designed to work on shared-IP hosting (such as GAE), so there are some SSL extensions that have various support on browsers (SNI/VIP).
2. Queries are quite weak on Datastore. They are also expensive. There are two ways to do analytics:

   a. Create a set of sharded counters and update the counter every time an event happens (= a financial transaction). We use this and is works well. The only downside is that this is "online" analytics. You can not add additional analytics parameters for the past data.

   b. Upload (anonymized) data to [Google Big Query](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/) and do analytics there.
3. Datastore has a limitation of about 5 writes-updates/s to a SINGLE entity or entity group (some sources say 1 w/s). There is no limitation on parallel writes to different entities. Remember, GAE is a distributed system where all apps use ONE BigTable database under the hood. So this is pretty scalable.
4. I don't have experience with this, but there are various reports on the net. See this http://www.listry.com/blog/2010/03/google-app-engine-cold-start-guide-for

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about other topics, but what I can tell you is that we use a combination of Guice + jersey to substitute Spring :) its better for GAE if we take into account rhe startup time